# fetch the id of a looped checkbox element

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, element, fetch

I have a single checkbox which is looped on a table variable in apex. When I check for the checked checkboxes and print the ids, it gives me the same id because it is the same element.

```
<div id="elementsToOperateOn">
loop...
<apex:inputcheckbox id="Productcheck" disabled="true" value="{!value.selectCheck}" />

var selectedVar = new Array();
$('#elementsToOperateOn :input:checked').each(function() { 
   alert($('#elementsToOperateOn :input:checked'.attr('id'));
   selectedVar.push(this);
});
```

This always populates the same id for the input checkbox. Is there any way to dynamically add an index?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, couldn't you just add a loop counter variable, and then use it to uniquely identify each checkbox? For example, something like this (the syntax is probably not correct but you get the idea):

```
<apex:inputcheckbox id="Productcheck{!loopCounter}"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I have already tried that. The error that I receive is:- Literal value is required for attribute id in <apex:inputcheckbox>. The id attribute has to be a static value. Thanks,
Kaustav